# Mixed models in R

Tags: mixed-model

I am trying to compare air temperature data for 6 different treatments performed during 3 years in 5 different sites. I would like to know if the temperature differs between treatment but also between years and sites. I m new in R so I wanted to know which model is recommended to use in this case. lme or lmer? any help with the script will be any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don’t automatically [think random effects](https://fharrell.com/post/re).

Comment: Were several treatments applied to the same sites ? I assume so because there are 6 treatments and only 5 sites .

Comment: thanks CarolZ! yes the same 6 treatments were applied to each site

Comment: mixedm<-lme(Temp ~ treat * Hour,  random = ~ 1 | Hour/site, data = SC)  this is my  script but I dont know how to add years. Thanks!